# Selecting a sub-property in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, object, substring, filtering, event-viewer

I have a long list of objects in PowerShell (more specifically, a list of Windows events from the `Get-EventLog` cmdlet) that I want to filter out to find who accessed my machine. I used the following:

`Get-EventLog -LogName Security -InstanceId 4672 | Select-Object -Property TimeGenerated, ReplacementStrings[1]`

But the output looks like:

```
TimeGenerated        ReplacementStrings[1]
-------------        ---------------------
6/17/2018 2:28:33 PM
6/17/2018 2:28:33 PM
6/17/2018 2:28:33 PM
6/17/2018 2:28:33 PM
6/17/2018 2:28:33 PM
...
```

I have no output at all the right column.

If I remove the `[1]` from `ReplacementString`:

```
TimeGenerated        ReplacementStrings
-------------        ------------------
6/17/2018 2:28:33 PM {S-1-2-3-4, Username1, blablabla...}
6/17/2018 2:28:33 PM {S-1-2-3-4, Username2, blablabla...}
6/17/2018 2:28:33 PM {S-1-2-3-4, Username2, blablabla...}
6/17/2018 2:28:33 PM {S-1-2-3-4, Username1, blablabla...}
6/17/2018 2:28:33 PM {S-1-2-3-4, Username3, blablabla...}
...
```

I want only the username field from `ReplacementStrings`.

I could use a `foreach` loop and manually concentrate to one string, but I want to keep the items as objects for later use, so this is not an option for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a calculated property:

```
Get-WinEvent ... |
  Select-Object -Property TimeGenerated,
                          @{Name='Username'; Expression={$_.ReplacementStrings[1]}}
```